# Anchor text annotation in R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, justify

EDIT* *Solution attached to bottom of this question*

I have a graph with an annotation that will change client to client. I need the text to be right justified with a maximum value, so that any client name length will not overlay other regions of the graph. Here is the code, and the product. Just want the text to always end next to the arrow, and grow out to the left.

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.33,0.17,0.16,0.14,0.2)
z<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))
client.name = "x"
client.year = 2015

ggplot<-  
  ggplot(z,aes(x = x,y = y,fill = y))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           fill = c("white","white","white","white","white","white",
                  "white","#c00000","#ed7d31","#ffc000","#92d050","#00b050"),width = .3)+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
# theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.77, y = .9, xend = 2.16, yend = .9),size=1.3,
               arrow = arrow(angle = 20, length = unit(0.25, "inches"), ends = "first", type = "open"),linetype="solid")+ 
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = c(0.167,0.415,0.58,0.73,0.9), 
           label = c("Disparaging","Unhappy","Ambivalent","Happy","Delighted"), 
           colour="white", fontface="bold", size=10) +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y =.9,  label = paste(client.name,client.year,paste0(.9, "%")), 
            fontface = "bold", hjust=0, size=10) 
ggplot
```

here is the result with a long client name, adjusted manually to sit next to the arrow

[image]

And here is the result with the smallest possible client name, "x".

[image]

I can get the text to where I want it by playing with values for each name, but need to to automatically adjust to the far right against the arrow head for any given name (bonus points, could I even have a line break for very long names!? No idea how).

Any ideas?

SOLUTION:
As pointed out by @baptiste, hjust is the key option here. I knew this to be the case, but wasn't aware that values of hjust outside of 0:1 change the position of the anchor as a function of string length. You can see I use -1 to get the positioning correct, when i should have instead manipulated X. I solved my problem by setting hjust to 1 (right justified) and adjusting X to the desired location.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: please make sure your code runs, there are so many things wrong with it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want right-justified text, you should probably use `hjust=1`

```
lab = strwrap(paste(client.name,client.year,paste0(.9, "%")),10)
annotate("text", x = 1.77, y =.9,  label = paste(lab, collapse="\n"), 
         fontface = "bold", hjust=1, size=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried to implement the hjust call (see the code), the problem is that the anchor for the text moves as a sunction of string length. I'm trying to set right-justified, with an anchor, thoughts?  Also, can you describe hjust to me? I thought hjust=1 should  set my text string to the right in the cuirrent plotting area, but I actually have to set values greater than 0:1 to move the string to where I need it, i.e. have x automatically set the start point for the right-justified string.

Comment: hjust=1 will right-justify the text, which means that it extends to the left of the x position (1.77 here to match the tip of the arrow). Values outside [0,1] are always confusing (and generally best avoided) as they correspond to a percentage of the string width IIRC.

Comment: In combination with your last comment, your suggestion solved my problem.  I will update my post to show the answer, and reasoning behind it that was crucial for my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, and this is only a partial solution.  For the bonus point question, try this approach.

```
  annotate("text", x = 1, y =.9,  label = paste("verylong\nclientname", client.year,paste0(.9, "%")), fontface = "bold", hjust=0, size=10)
```

[image]

How and where to insert the line break `\n` algorithmically is more complex.  You might say that 10 characters or more is a long client name.  Then, perhaps you can run `nchar()` on each client name and set up a test along the lines of this pseudo-code: ifelse(nchar > 10, insert line break at position 11, leave alone)

**EDIT regarding placement of the client name, date and percent**
Now you have me pondering!

Why don't you define `anchor <- .9` # using your current end point on the arrow?

Then you place your client name etc. with `x = anchor - .1` or some horizontal adjustment to the left?  On you current MWE data with x being mostly 1 and 2 it may be less efficacious, but with real data I think this might place the annotations snug to the arrow's end.

Comment: So if you're interested, I ended up setting my rules fro breaking the string array up as follows: 
  
`if (nchar(client.name) > 40) {warning("Client name is too long")}
if (nchar(client.name) > 20) {
  space.locs = as.data.frame(str_locate_all(client.name, " ")) #locate spaces in name
  space.mid = round(nrow(as.data.frame(space.locs))/2)# find middle space
  substr(client.name,space.locs[space.mid,1],space.locs[space.mid,1]) <- "\n" #add line break
}`